# How to use Big Commerce Order API and make customer pay?

Tags: bigcommerce

I would like to make an API call to Big Commerce backend to complete a purchase on a customer's behalf. Based on the API reference:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders#create-an-order

By default, I believe that one can only create an order that not yet paid by the customer. Please correct me if I am wrong.

So, my question is - **How do you make a payment on behalf of a customer for the order?** It is safe to assume that we have a tokenized credit card of our known customer in a payment gateway like Stripe.

My guess of how it could be done is when an order is created, I can set up a webhook to call the payment gateway to make a charge on the customer's credit card. Is this correct? Are there anything that I should watch out for?

Comment: Hi Yao, I'm curious where you ended up with this problem as I'm looking to do something similar for a client. Did you end up using Rebillia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you cannot use the BigCommerce API to process a payment or full transaction. We only allow payments through the control panel where you can enter credit card details or on the storefront made by the customer. If you'd like to make use of tokenization or recurring payments, it is better to use [Rebillia](https://www.rebillia.com/) or [Recharge](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/recurring-billing-by-recharge/) (apps).

As you stated, you would need to make a call to Stripe's API to charge the card on file with the customer's token. This should be fine. It won't make any calls back to BigCommerce, so I'd be mindful of error handling (such as if the card has expired) and how you'd retry or mark the order in BigCommerce. Depending on how it was configured, you would want to check order details to ensure you were only processing payments from API created orders.

I'm not sure of what PCI implications might be for the storage of the Stripe tokens. That would be another point for consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is very useful to know. ;)